# grep for a variable that contains "+"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Trying to pickup the second row using grep and it dosent work if it has a "+" character

i have tried with fgrep & instead of -P tried with Fx or x and -w but none of them worked.

File prereq.txt contains this :

```
WS+1                    whatever                                2222
WS--1                   whatever2                               1111
```

```sh
name="$(more prereq.txt | grep -P "(^|\s)$model($|\s)" | awk '{print $2}')"
```

```
Result :

model=WS--1

Output :

echo $name

whatever2
```

it works on the places where it shas - or -- but dosent work if it has "+"

```
Result :

model=WS+1

Output :

echo $name
```

Expected Result :

```
model=WS+1

Output :

echo $name
whatever
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and make a clear distinction between code and regular text?  For example, is `it works on the place...` actually part of your input file, or is that part of your question.

Comment: Edited Tim , Any suggestions ?

Comment: I have seen many [*usless uses of cat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) but this is the first time I have seen a *usless use of more*. For better style and efficiency write `grep ... file` instead of `more file | grep ...`

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is, that `grep` interpret the `+` as a quantifier and not as a string.

You can simplify your code using `awk` alone.

```
$ model=WS--1
$ awk -v model=$model '$1==model {print $2}' prereq.txt
whatever2
```

and

```
$ model=WS+1
$ awk -v model=$model '$1==model print {$2}' prereq.txt
whatever
```

With `-v model=$model` we set the `awk` variable `model` with the shell value of `model`. Then for each line, where the first column has this value, the second column is printed.

Answer (score 1):

This may be easier with Perl, since Perl's regexes support a `\Q...\E` notation to disable any special characters in an interpolated variable:

```
name="$(
  export model # export $model into environment
  perl -ne ' if (m/(^|\s)\Q$ENV{model}\E($|\s)/) {
               my @fields = split /\s+/, $_;
               print "$fields[1]\n";
             }
           '
)"
```

Comment: You forgot to apply \Q and \E in your example. BTW, Since the OP was willing to use the `-P` option of grep, he could have used this trick in grep too; no need to revert to Perl.

Comment: @user1934428: Re: \Q and \E: whoops, ha! Fixed, thanks! Re: `-P`: That's usually true, but it wouldn't work for cases such as `model='\E'`. So using Perl interpolation, rather than Bash interpolation, is more robust IMHO.

Comment: Right you are, though I suspect that an engineer who calls his model `\E` will be shot faster than he can publish his design....

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
model="WS[+]1"
grep -P "(^|\s)$model($|\s)" prereq.txt | awk '{print $2}'
```